# Design bug in IE11 on Win8.1

Tags: bug, design

I see a problem with the site rendering in IE11 (desktop) on my Windows 8.1 system. This doesn't affect IE 11 in Win 7, and doesn't apply to Chrome, FF, Safari or Opera on Win 8.1.

Question page:

[image]

Front page:

[image]

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 and you just gave me a reason to open IE11 which I normally avoid at all costs ;-) But I don't see the same problem...weird

Comment: This also exhibits the tag-text alignment problem I posted about (see especially "(graphics)" tag at bottom of the second image).

Comment: Oh it's hilarious that you used screenshots from the Mac question to post an IE bug... Alan.. you are my hero :)

Comment: Should we test Netscape Compatibility?

Comment: @Scott I'm glad somebody noticed!  :)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I'm testing on IE 11.0.9600.16521, Windows 8.1

Comment: @AlanGilbertson bonus points if that was from IE running on a Mac inside Parallels or Virtualbox...

Comment: Nah. I only use my MacBook for beta testing. I work in Windows because I can work faster in that environment.

Comment: @jin I've not had a chance to dig in and figure out the source of the problem. It doesn't go away, though, so it may be a peculiarity of add-ons or local configuration. I'll poke around.

Comment: I had the [same problem](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/938/is-this-just-me-or-is-the-site-broken?noredirect=1#comment2703_938) on Win7 and IE 11. It was intermittent.